# Python script accepting optional multiple inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have something like this:

```
python example.py -i input.txt
```

where the script is required to have at least one input, and I want it to have the option of accepting multiple inputs such as:

```
python example.py -i input1.txt -i input2.txt -i input3.txt
```

I've looked into Python's argparse module so I have something like:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", help="takes in an input file", action="store_true")
```

But I'm not exactly sure how to make it so it can have multiple inputs and be able to retrieve them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allow an option to receive any number of arguments [using the `nargs` parameter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-i', nargs='+')
>>> parser.parse_args('-i input1.txt input2.txt input3.txt'.split())
Namespace(i=['input1.txt', 'input2.txt', 'input3.txt'])
```